# Get date of when user in Azure Active Directory was disabled

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, active-directory

Is there any ways to find when an account was disabled? I looked online and was only able to find way to get whenchanged to get las modified date for AD.

`Get-ADUser -ObjectId $id -SearchBase 'OUDISTINGUISHEDNAME' -PROPERTIES WhenChanged`

Is there something similar for Azure AD? Ideally, I would like to get date when the account was disabled. But if not possible last modified will be good too.

Comment: I believe `whenchanged` takes into account any changes made on the object itself. I don't have AzureAD, but is there any difference than just searching `Get-AsADUser $user -Properties WhenChanged`? I'd assume it have the same properties.

Comment: If you want a more accurate date, going off *regular* AD cmdlets, you'd have to use `Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetaData` for every DC and check against the `LastOriginatingChangeTime` under `UserAccountControl` for the disabled date.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I get nothing back when I do `Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $id | Select WhenChanged`. I am trying to use the following `Get-ADUser -identity $id -SearchBase 'OUDISTINGUISHEDNAME' -PROPERTIES WhenChanged` but am getting "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specific named property" error. Is this code working for you?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala got the Get-AdUser working. Thanks

Comment: pardon the late reply. Figured you wanted an Azure cmdlet based answer so I held off on commenting further.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute whenChanged doesn't tell you when a account got disabled, it only tells you when the last write operation to this object did happen, nothing more.

For AD (EventId 4725) as well as AzureAd you have to ask the log to answer this question:

```
#add UPN here
$upn = [userPirncipalName]
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "ActivityDisplayName eq 'Disable account' and TargetResources/any(t:t/UserPrincipalName eq '$upn')"
```

Note: Azure Ad keeps the log only for 30 days. Also there is no guarantee by when AzureAd writes operations to the AuditLog - they only say in 95% of the cases the information may be available within 2 minutes. Values in the filter = case sensitive.

Comment: When I go into on-premise-> Event Viewer -> Windows Log -> Security then filter out using EventId 4725 I get nothing back. I changed it to 30 days and I didn't get anything back. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you need to have the right auditing options activated to log the related events:, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4725 -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-user-account-management to get the current config you can run ```auditpol /get /category=*```